# java swing nullpointer exeption whilst adding buttons

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, nullpointerexception, jbutton

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

So i was trying to do a java-swing-gui for a school project and therefor I have to add 72 Buttons (idk) to a JPanel element.
I tried using a for-loop:

```java
for (JButton btn : btns) {
    panel.add(btn);
}
```

but it didnt really work out and threw a nullPointerExeption.
Any suggestions?

Here is the full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.DimensionUIResource;

import java.awt.*;

public class mädn extends JFrame{
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static JButton[] fields = new JButton[72];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new mädn();
    }

    public mädn() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new DimensionUIResource(500, 500));
        frame.setTitle("Mensch Ärger Dich Nicht");

        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 11));
        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        
        for (JButton field : fields) {
            field.setSize(20, 20);
            panel.add(field);
        }

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven’t initialised the contents of the array

Comment: When creating an object array, the contents of the array is initially set to `null` (each element), you need to fill the array with values before you can use them.  You can use a loop to create each element and populate the panel.  Also, `setSize`, in this context, isn't going to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an array like this:

```java
static JButton[] fields = new JButton[72];
```

that array is empty. In other words, even though that array has the capacity to keep 72 buttons, it doesn't have those buttons yet, you have to add them manually, like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
    fields[i] = new JButton();
}
```

But if you don't, `fields[i]` will be `null` by default, and so when you try to do `field.setSize(20, 20)`, that field is null and will cause a `NullPointerException`.

Primitive arrays also have default values. For example elements of an array of `int` are all `0`, and elements of an array of `boolean` are all `false`. The same is true for non-primitive arrays (like `JButton`), the elements are all by default `null`.

Your final code would look something like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
    fields[i] = new JButton();
    fields[i].setSize(20, 20);
    panel.add(fields[i]);
}
```

or:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
    JButton field = new JButton();
    fields[i] = field;
    field.setSize(20, 20);
    panel.add(field);
}
```

or even shorter:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
    var field = fields[i] = new JButton();
    field.setSize(20, 20);
    panel.add(field);
}
```

Also consider turning that `72` into a constant (a `static final` field).

Comment: Thanks a lot SMMH, helped me solve this problem

Comment: @JonasHaardoerfer No problem man, could you assign my answer as the correct answer so it gets a green checkmark?